# play: scala Json.format for date

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have been having problem with my Json conversion in my `play-framework` api server for a while and have always been working with tedious workaround. I think that it is a simple and common problem and thus would like to solve it once and for all so that I can have a more maintainable code

I'd need to convert my `case class` to Json. I have been hard coding a `jsonify` function that return hardcoded member variable one by one [so tedious but worked]

How do I provide `implicit Format` for `inner case class`? I can't override (and don't know which method to override albeit having read the related docs again and again)

```
case class CaseObject (
  id: String,
  title: String,
  createdDate: java.util.Date // here is the problem
) {

}

object CaseObject {
    // is this how to override?
    // val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    //  implicit object dateWrites extends Writes[java.util.Date] {
    //    def writes(date: java.util.Date): JsValue = {
    //      JsString(formatter.format(createdDate))
    //    }
    //  }

    implicit val CaseObjectFormat = Json.format[CaseObject]
    implicit val CaseObjectReads = Json.reads[CaseObject]
    implicit val CaseObjectWrites = Json.writes[CaseObject]
    implicit val CaseObjectBson = Macros.handler[CaseObject]

    // tried circe as well...
    private[this] def fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM- 
    dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
    implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default
    implicit val dateEncoder: Encoder[Date] = 
        Encoder[String].contramap(fmt.format)
    implicit val dateDecoder: Decoder[Date] = 
        Decoder[String].emapTry(str => Try(fmt.parse(str)))

 }
```

Please help.. I have cracked my head for days for this trivial issue.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you use java.util.Date? java.time package contains bunch of more safe and efficient classes for date, time, and time-zones

Answer (score 4):

You need to import generic date format

```
import play.api.data.format.Formats.dateFormat
```

or define [custom one](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.format.Formats$)

```
implicit val format = dateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import java.util.Date


case class CaseObject(
                         id: String,
                         title: String,
                         createdDate: java.util.Date // here is the problem
                       )

implicit val j = Json.format[CaseObject]

val c = CaseObject("1", "new title", new Date())

println(Json.toJson(c))
```

I didn't quite understand your question. This one converts to json if it's what you want.

Comment: `No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for java.util.Date in the implicit scope`

Comment: import java.util.Date was missing. Try edited answer